# Is Class variable in swift can only be accessed by class function...?

Tags: swift

I cant access "price" variable without a class function , may i know why ?

here is the code.

```
class var price : Int {
      return 25000
    }

 class func display()
    {
        println("The \(name) with \(model) was released in \(year) with rs.\(price)")
    }
```

Comment: Put the class var price:Int under a super class. Then it will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class var belong to a class, not the instance. You can access it via:

1. the class name: `MyClass.price`
2. `self.dynamicType.price` (for a function inside the class)
3. `myVar.dynamicType.price` (assuming `myVar` is an instance of the class).